# Exclude unexpected characters in a column

Tags: pandas

The final output is to exclude unexpected characters in product title.

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product': [['cream', 'with', 'vegetable', 'oil', '(4+2', 'free)', '170', 'g', 'almarai', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']],
                   })
```

**Expected output**

 1. To keep text and number only.

 2. To drop everything else

```
creamwithvegetableoil42free170galmarai
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to keep the `+` as well?

Comment: sorry, please drop + too. Thanks

Comment: I am looking for way to drop everything, keep text and number only. Thanks

Comment: I have a column with a lot of unexpected characters. Kindly help me with a formula to keep text and number only and drop the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `Series.explode` to unnest your list to a row for each element

Then we can use `Series.str.extractall` with `\w+` and `\d+` to get all word characters + numbers out of your column.

Finally we use `GroupBy.agg` with `''.join` to concatenate your strings back to each other:

```
(df['product'].explode()
 .str.extractall('(\w+|\d+)')
 .replace('NaN', '')
 .groupby(level=0).agg(''.join))

                                        0
0  creamwithvegetableoil42free170galmarai
```